# xamarin.forms Why do I click anywhere on the page to focus on the first entry?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have several entries on the ContentPage

But wherever I click on the page, it automatically focuses on the first entry

[image]

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Entry />
        <Entry />
        <Entry />
        <Entry />
        <Entry />
        <Entry />
        <Label Text="test" />
        <Entry />
        <Entry />
        <Entry />

        <Label Text="test2" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: You've shown us absolutely no code.

Comment: See the gif ....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you show the code in the xaml? I had done a simple to test and the first entry would be focused just when I clicked it.

Comment: Can you reproduce it when restarting app from scratch? Could be related to hotreload dynamically added entries..

Comment: The same exact code works just fine for me. No Entry is focused after the app launches and an Entry is only focused on after I click on it. Clicking on the "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms" of either of the Labels does nothing.